# How to convert 8.991M and 0.785M to number like 8.911.000 and 785.000 in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to convert 8.991M to million in Excel, -> 8.991.000

Here are some examples I have in the data set, with negative values as well.

```
0.785M
0.452M
0.414M
7.459M
3.355M
3.548M
-0.405M
-2.549M
1.164M
-11.463M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### VALUE & SUBSTITUTE

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),"M",""))*1000
```

Format cells by using e.g. `Right-Click > Format Cells > Number Tab > Select Number`. Set `Decimal Places` to `0` and tick `Use Thousands Separator`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1** use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(--LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*10^6,"#,##0"),",",".")
```

This assumes US locale:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*1000000
```

this will turn the cell value to a number you can later work with.